# hyperref error using latex: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@temp"

Tags: hyperref

I have a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04 including TeX Live.  A LaTeX file which worked well under Ubuntu 12.04 now gives error  "Illegal parameter number in definition of `\Hy@temp`" when calling latex at every `\citeads` command (but not for pdflatex).  The file is `example.tex` at `http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~rutte101/Report_recipe.html`
and is a decades-old latex primer, more recently expanded with bibtex cite macros that turn in-text citations into web browser openers for the astronomy literature database at NASA.  These macros were contributed and are recommended by the journal Astronomy & Astrophysics.  The errors are non-fatal (answering with "s" produces the proper `example.dvi` result).

Has something changed in `hyperref`?  Is there a mistake in the `citeads` macros in that file?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommandtwoopt{\citetads}[3][][]{%
  \href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/#3}{%
    \def\hyper@linkstart##1##2{}%
    \let\hyper@linkend\@empty%
    \citet[#1][#2]{#3}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \citetads{1981ApJ...247L..97M}
\end{document}
```

**February 27 2019:** solved by linuxss privately with

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\sppresslink{\def\hyper@linkstart##1##2{}\let\hyper@linkend\@empty}
 \newcommandtwoopt{\citeads}[3][][]{
   \href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/#3}
        {\sppresslink \citealp[#1][#2]{#3}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the same error compiling the file with TeX Live 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013 and also with the development version of 2014; even after enabling the two `breakurl` lines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem

Comment: @egreg: In your first comment your reproduced it.  I think the MWE above constructed by Heiko Oberdiek should reproducibly give the same error unless a latex wrapper calls /nonstopmode.  I still hope for a guru to solve this problem.

Comment: I am a bit(?) late to the party. However, If there's a `#` anywhere in the URL, escape it. Like so `\#`

Comment: @manucpp Thanks for that! Came here from a Google search having the same problem, and your suggestion fixed it.

Comment: Problem is ## in \href expansion so you can just hide empty link macros in unexpandable  command:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\bibcite{mycite}{{1}{1992}{{Carlsson}}{{}}}

\protected\def\disableLink{
  \def\hyper@linkstart##1##2{}%
  \let\hyper@linkend\@empty
  }
\newcommandtwoopt{\citetads}[3][][]{%
  \href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/#3}{%
   \disableLink
    \citet[#1][#2]{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \citetads{mycite}
\end{document}

Answer (score 3):

The following fix inserting `\nonstopmode` and `\errorstopmode` works by having latex not stop at an error within `\citeads`, but this will make latex also not stop at a serious error in a citation.  I would rather have a recoding of the macro in the above MWE to not get the "`Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@temp.`" warning.  So help is still welcome!

(apology: I don't know how to format the following properly; the stackexchange entry window undoes the newlines and spacings, so I added a newline per line)

```
\makeatletter
 \newcommandtwoopt{\citetads}[3][][]{%
  \nonstopmode%
  \href{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/#3}{\def\hyper@linkstart##1##2{}%
    \let\hyper@linkend\@empty\citet[#1][#2]{#3}}%
  \errorstopmode}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

When I compiled your MWE, I get the following result as output (Windows Machine with TeXLive 2013 installed from iso image):
[image]
[image]

Now, I feel there is problem with the installation of TeXLive. If you have installed it from the terminal, then make sure is the command `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` rather than simply `sudo apt-get install texlive` or `sudo apt-get install texlive-base`. Second, If it is from the iso, then the only way I feel should be **updation**. Try to update *all the packages* (if you can)(the command is `tlmgr update all`) else the packages `natbib`, `twoopt` and `hyperref`. This should solve the problem. The commands are : 
`tlmgr update self` (requires sometimes. Better if it is done i.e Updating the TeXLive Manager before updating the packages). Then `tlmgr update --package name--`. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention!  I ran sudo apt-get install texlive-full.  It added two GB (which is a concern, this modern solid-state disk is not the size I was used to).  No change, the same error.

Comment: Try to update the package hyperref, `tlmgr update hyperref`

Comment: Tried tlmgr update hyperref: (running on Debian, switching to user mode!) cannot setup TLPDB in /home/rutten/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.tlmgr
so I googled and found and ran: tlmgr init-usertree and then tlmgr update hyperref and got (running on Debian, switching to user mode!) /usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).

Comment: Apology for very bad layout above.  This form doesn't let me type Emacs-style and restricted the length to the above.   It throws me out when I type a return... No idea what mini-Markdown means.

Comment: The "linkendempty" was caused by not copying the \makeatletter and \makeatother into the MWE (by Heiko Oberdiek).  And @egreg: Ubuntu 12.04 seems to have used tex-live of 2009; so I guess

Comment: I suggest you install TeXLive from the iso . Check here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: I installed tex on a brandnew Mac and ran latex on the above MWE.  It stopped at the same "Illegal parameter number" error.  This means that installing the very newest texlive doesn't do, since others don't have that either (most of my colleagues in astrophysics use macs and many use the above macro).  As to my Ubuntu 14.04, @egreg above already indicated that even the next texlive will give this error.  So the problem remains.  I hoped that perhaps some recoding of the macros in the MWE would make these error stops go away.  Help welcome!

Comment: It goes on very well on my machine. Don't know why the problem is persisting....

Comment: thanks again.  Seems to me your Windows latex caller uses something as latex -interaction=nonstopmode foo.tex?  My "answer" below follows that notion; it works, but is an ugly and inappropriate fix.